# difference between expected values of distributions

Tags: probability-theory

let us assume two distributions $p$ and $p'$ over the set of naturals $N$.

Is it true the following property?

$\sum_{n \in N} p(n) \cdot n \le \sum_{n \in N} p'(n) \cdot n$

IFF

for all $0 \le u \le 1$

$\sum_{n \in N} p(n) \cdot u^{n} \ge \sum_{n \in N} p'(n) \cdot u^n$

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Call $X$ a random variable with distribution $p$ and $Y$ a random variable with distribution $p'$, then one considers the assertions:

1. $E[X]\leqslant E[Y]$
2. $E[u^X]\geqslant E[u^Y]$ for every $u$ in $[0,1]$

Assertion 2. implies assertion 1. because $X=\lim\limits_{u\to1}\frac1{1-u}\cdot(1-u^X)$ and the limit is monotonous.

Assertion 1. does not imply assertion 2., as witnessed by the case  $E[u^X]=\frac23+\frac13u$ and $E[u^Y]=\frac34+\frac14u^2$.